# How to use a variable defined inside one function from another function?

Tags: python, function, variables

If I have this:

```
def oneFunction(lists):
    category=random.choice(list(lists.keys()))
    word=random.choice(lists[category])

def anotherFunction():
    for letter in word:              #problem is here
        print("_",end=" ")
```

I have previously defined `lists`, so `oneFunction(lists)` works perfectly.

My problem is calling `word` in line 6. I have tried to define `word` outside the first function with the same `word=random.choice(lists[category])` definition, but that makes `word` always the same, even if I call `oneFunction(lists)`.

I want to have a different `word` every time I call the first function and then the second.

Can I do this without defining that `word` outside the `oneFunction(lists)`?

Comment: Why not pass `word` as an argument to `anotherFunction`? Consider `def anotherFunction(word):` and calling it accordingly.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

One approach would be to make `oneFunction` return the word so that you can use `oneFunction` instead of `word` in `anotherFunction` :

```
def oneFunction(lists):
    category = random.choice(list(lists.keys()))
    return random.choice(lists[category])

    
def anotherFunction():
    for letter in oneFunction(lists):              
        print("_", end=" ")
```

Another approach is making `anotherFunction` accept `word` as a parameter which you can pass from the result of calling `oneFunction`:

```
def anotherFunction(words):
    for letter in words:              
        print("_", end=" ")
anotherFunction(oneFunction(lists))
```

And finally, you could define both of your functions in a class, and make `word` a member:

```
class Spam:
    def oneFunction(self, lists):
        category=random.choice(list(lists.keys()))
        self.word=random.choice(lists[category])

    def anotherFunction(self):
        for letter in self.word:              
            print("_", end=" ")
```

Once you make a class, you have to instantiate an instance and access the member functions:

```
s = Spam()
s.oneFunction(lists)
s.anotherFunction()
```

Comment: thank you!
In the first approach, can you please explain me exactly what the `self` part does? Is it an argument for the function?

Comment: @JNat: `self` gives you the reference to the current object, much like what `this` (pointer) or `this` (variable) serves in notable OOP Languages.

Comment: python tells me `self` is not defined... why is that? do I need to import some module before or something?

Comment: @JNat: You have to make a class, the same way I showed in the example. I think you are not comfortable with OO so I will update my answer to add more details.

Comment: I did define a class with the two functions inside of it, but when call the first function (`Spam.oneFunction(self,lists)`) he tells me `self` is not defined...

Comment: that final addition you made is supposed to be written outside the class definition right?

Comment: @JNat: Yes, Just define the class, and then the next three statements place is somewhere outside your class.

Comment: Python tells me (after I added those three statements) that global name word is not defined... WHY?

Comment: @JNat: Did you use it as it is. Did you prefix self, before every occurrence of word?

Comment: I missed the `self` in one `word`... that was it. Can you explain to me why I need those last three statements?

Comment: @JNat: Its difficult to describe in few lines. I would suggest either you read about [Classes](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html) are raise a separate question.

Comment: the two statements:
`s.oneFunction(lists)
s.anotherFunction()`
execute the functions. So they really are not needed in order to define the class. Is that it?

Answer (score 33):

Everything in python is considered as object so functions are also objects. So you can use this method as well.

```
def fun1():
    fun1.var = 100
    print(fun1.var)

def fun2():
    print(fun1.var)

fun1()
fun2()

print(fun1.var)
```

Comment: This approach is an abuse of function attributes, and future calls will overwrite the value from previous calls.

Comment: I really like this approach. For the purpose of inspecting variables inside functions in unit tests, I think this is a great approach.

Answer (score 9):

The simplest option is to use a global variable.
Then create a function that gets the current word.

Notice that to *read* global variables inside a function, you do *not* need to use the `global` keyword. However, to *write* to a global variable within a function, you *do* have to use the `global` keyword in front of the variable declaration within the function, or else the function will consider it a separate, local variable, and not update the global variable when you write to it.

```
current_word = ''
def oneFunction(lists):
    global current_word
    word=random.choice(lists[category])
    current_word = word
    
def anotherFunction():
    for letter in get_word():              
          print("_",end=" ")

 def get_word():
      return current_word
```

The advantage of this is that maybe your functions are in different modules and need to access the variable.

Answer (score 4):

```
def anotherFunction(word):
    for letter in word:              
        print("_", end=" ")

def oneFunction(lists):
    category = random.choice(list(lists.keys()))
    word = random.choice(lists[category])
    return anotherFunction(word)
```

Comment: You can pass the word variable from the first function 'oneFunction' to the other function. However, I guess you have to put the other function first less you get an error, "anotherFunction is not defined". Also, I noticed, you are not doing anything with the 'letter' variable that you have referenced in the for-loop

Answer (score 1):

so i went ahead and tried to do what came to my head
You could easily make the first function to **return** the word then use the function in the *another function* while passing in an the same object in the new function like so:

```
def oneFunction(lists):
    category=random.choice(list(lists.keys()))
    word=random.choice(lists[category])
    return word

def anotherFunction(sameList):
    for letter in oneFunction(sameList):             
        print(letter)
```

Comment: Hey! This _should_ work — something similar was suggested in [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10139935/1328704) :)

Answer (score 0):

```py
def oneFunction(lists):
    category=random.choice(list(lists.keys()))
    word=random.choice(lists[category])
    return word

def anotherFunction():
    for letter in word:             
        print("_",end=" ")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def abc():
    global x
    x = 4 +5 
    return x

def klm():
    y = x + 5
    print(y)
```

When we want to use a function variable into another function , we can simply use 'global' keyword.
Note: This is just a simple usage, but if you want to use it within a class environment, then you can refer above answers.

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1:

Either define variable as global, then print the variable value from the second script. Ex:

```
python_file1.py
x = 20

def test():
  global x
  return x
test()

python_file2.py
from python_file1 import *
print(x)
```

---

Solution 2:

This solution can be useful when the variable in function 1 is not predefined. In this case need to store the output of first python file in a new variable in second python file. Ex:

```
python_file1.py
def add(x,y):
    return x + y


if __name__ =="__main__"
add(x=int(input("Enter x"),y = int(input("Enter y"))

python_file2.py
from python_file1 import * 
# Assign functions of python file 1 in a variable of 2nd python file
add_file2 = add(5,6)

def add2()
  print(add_file2)

add2()
```