# How to use classes to access a variable in function_one from function_two?

Tags: python, class, variables, python-2.7, global-variables

Contents of file_one.py:

```
from file_two import *

def function_one():
    my_list = []
    function_two()

function_one()
```

Contents of file_two.py:

```
def function_two():
    my_list.append(1)
    print my_list
```

Error on running 'file_one.py':

`NameError: global name 'my_list' is not defined`

The above example is a simplified version of what i am actually trying to implement however it produces the same error and i believe it replicates the same logic.

In the actual implementation, as a newbie, i was importing a file full of functions (file_two.py) into file_one.py and then just using the function name in file_one.py when i wanted to call it.

This worked fine until i had to use a variable from a function in file_one.py in a function in file_two.py (as demonstrated above).  Hence my need to understand classes.

This seems to be a very succinct description and implementation of classes:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/10139935/1063287

However i don't (that i can currently see) need to use a function from a class, just a variable.

I get stuck here thinking whether i just need to create a simpler class file (without functions) and if so:

- what would be required to be in it (in regards to syntax etc)?
- and how would i reference the variables in it from elsewhere (again in regards to syntax etc)?

Comment: I don't quite understand what you're trying to achieve here... why can you not pass `my_list` as a function parameter to `function_two()`?

Comment: thank you, i'm not sure how scalable this will be in the future (so i will have to learn more about classes), but i had not thought of that and passing the variables through as parameters worked a treat.  thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think usage of classes is essential to achieve some sort of state:

state.py:

```
my_list = []
```

file_two.py:

```
import state

def function_two():
    state.my_list.append(2)
    print state.my_list
```

file_one.py:

```
from file_two import function_two
import state

def function_one():
    state.my_list.append(1)
    function_two()

function_one()
# this will print out [1, 2]
```

Of course you could use classes as well, but it doesn't sound like you really need to.

I would recommend against using `global` although it could work, I find it makes less clear where variables are coming from.

**UPDATE:**

Of course if all you want to do is make a variable from `function_one` available in `function_two` you can always just pass it as a parameter like this:

file_two.py

```
def function_two(some_list):
    some_list.append(2)
    print some_list
```

file_one.py

```
from file_two import function_two

def function_one():
    my_list = []
    my_list.append(1)
    function_two(my_list)

function_one()
# [1, 2]
```

Objects and classes are quite powerful, but they're not necessary to write well-structured/scalable code (that's to address the concern you expressed in your comment above). Passing parameters is a basic component of programming in Python, you should find yourself using it all the time wether you're making a very basic or a very complex application.

Comment: i used your original suggestion of passing the variables through as function parameters.  if you'd like to add that suggestion to this reply then i can mark it as the correct answer.  thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out, the use of classes is not essential, 
then the code below is really poor but gives you an idea of 
'How to use classes to access a variable '

```
def function_two():
    function_one.my_list.append(1)
    print function_one.my_list


class function_one():
    my_list = [] 
    @staticmethod
    def __call__():
        function_one.my_list = []
        function_two()
function_one = function_one()
```

Now function one behaves as a function and has an attribute my_list accessible from outside.

But you should consider passing my_list to finction_two as a parameter...