# Extract value from Python array and use in another def

Tags: python

I have updated this code with modifications suggested by Reticality.  I would like to access the value of hands_count which resides within the array of packets[] and or the array type[] below.

```
def history2packets(self, history, game_id, cache):
    game_index = 0
    player_list_index = 7
    packets = []
    for event in history:
        self.event = event
        type = event[0]
        if type == "game":
            (type, level, hand_serial, hands_count, time, variant, betting_structure, player_list, dealer, serial2chips) = event
            if len(serial2chips) > 1:
                nochips = 0
                for (serial, chips) in serial2chips.iteritems():
                    if serial == 'values':
                        continue
                    packets.append(PacketPokerPlayerChips(game_id = game_id,
                                                          serial = serial,
                                                          bet = nochips,
                                                          money = chips))
            packets.append(PacketPokerInGame(game_id = game_id,
                                             players = player_list))
            if self.previous_dealer == dealer:
                previous_dealer = -1
            else:
                previous_dealer = self.previous_dealer
            packets.append(PacketPokerDealer(game_id = game_id,
                                             dealer = dealer,
                                             previous_dealer = previous_dealer))
            self.previous_dealer = dealer
            packets.append(PacketPokerStart(game_id = game_id,
                                            hand_serial = hand_serial,
                                            hands_count = hands_count,
                                            time = time,
                                            level = level))
```

and use that value in another function like so:

```
def autoDeal(self):
    self.cancelDealTimeout()
    if not self.allReadyToPlay():
        for player in self.game.playersAll():
            if player.getUserData()['ready'] == False:
                for avatar in self.avatar_collection.get(player.serial):
                    if self.factory.verbose > 1:
                        self.message("Player %d marked as having a bugous PokerProcessingHand protocol" %  player.serial)
                        avatar.bugous_processing_hand = True
    if self.event[2] != 0:    
        self.beginTurn()
        self.update()
    else:
        reactor.callLater(10, self.beginTurn)
        self.update()
```

I am still getting an error but a different one.

```
2015-02-19 22:10:11-0500 [-] Unhandled Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/twisted/application/app.py", line 445, in startReactor
    self.config, oldstdout, oldstderr, self.profiler, reactor)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/twisted/application/app.py", line 348, in runReactorWithLogging
    reactor.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/twisted/internet/base.py", line 1170, in run
    self.mainLoop()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/twisted/internet/base.py", line 1179, in mainLoop
    self.runUntilCurrent()
--- <exception caught here> ---
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/twisted/internet/base.py", line 778, in runUntilCurrent
    call.func(*call.args, **call.kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/pokernetwork/pokertable.py", line 738, in autoDeal
    if self.event[2] != 0:
exceptions.AttributeError: PokerTable instance has no attribute 'event'
```

Both function are within the same module and class. What else could be wrong?

Comment: See e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/q/10139866/3001761. And once you get it working, I **strongly** recommend you take this over to http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: I really hope this is a just for fun thing ...

Comment: @jonrsharpe thanks for the link. If I can get it to work i will take it over to codeview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable `event` is defined within the local scope of the method `history2packets`. If you refer to it within another scope (e.g. a function or method) it will raise a `NameError`, as it was not defined in that scope.

A quick way to fix this is putting a line saying `global event` at the top of both methods, but this is usually frowned upon. Another way is returning `event` from `history2packets` and make the parameters of `autoDeal` `autoDeal(self, event)`. This means you could call:

```
e = history2packets(...)
# 5 lines later
autodeal(e)
```

Another way to do this assumes `history2packets` and `autoDeal` are 2 methods of the same class. Modify dome code here in `history2packets`:

```
    packets = []
    for event in history:
         self.event = event
         type = event[0]
```

And then, make `autoDeal`

```
def autoDeal(self):
    self.cancelDealTimeout()
    if not self.allReadyToPlay():
        # Some lines later
    if self.event[2] != 0:  # This is the changed line  
        # Same as before
```

Comment: Please have another look, I have implemented your suggestions but there is still a problem. I am really trying to understand this, your answer seems comprehensive but so far I haven't any luck with any of the scenarios you have provided.

Comment: That means they are not in the same instance of a class. You should then probably do the `global event` solution writing `global event` at the top of `history2packets`, so `event` is in the global scope.

Comment: I couldn't get the history2packets() method to give up the value of hands_count.  I believe that hands_count didn't get populated at the instant when autoDeal() needed it.   However,  I was able to achieve the delay of the first deal by globalizing two other variables in another module.   So, instead of using the hands_count variable as the crux for the delay, I used the servers change of state variables, (e.g. when the game server changed from registering for a game to running of the game).  I used the globalized variable named old_state as the test in autoDeal() in order to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

The variable `event` is defined in `history2packets`, but it is not global. So when you refer to a variable with this name in a different function, that raises a `NameError`.