# Python Import file module into another

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I am trying to import a variable called **log_entry_counts** from a python file called **data_processed.py**  into anothe file in the same directory called **failed_hmac.py** to do some percentage calculations but after importing, i am not able to access the variables inside the imported module(file). Here is the first file name data_processed.py . 
import os
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from collections import Counter

```
def dataCount(folderName):
    #count = 0
    log_entry_counts = Counter()
    today_date = datetime.today()
    date_ranges = [
                    ('30 Days', today_date - timedelta(days=30)),
                   # ('3 months', today-date - timedelta(days=90)),
                    #('year', today-date - timedelta(days=365))
                  ]
    for path, dirs, files in os.walk(folderName):
        for dirname in dirs:
            log_date = (os.path.join(path, dirname))

        for items in files:
            if items != ".DS_Store":
                try:
                    log_date = datetime.strptime(path[39:47], '%m%d%Y')
                    for text, dr in date_ranges:
                        if log_date >= dr:
                            log_entry_counts[text] += 1
                except ValueError:
                    print 'This line has a problem:', log_date

    total = 0

    print log_entry_counts['30 Days'] 

def main():

    filePath = 'file.txt'

    hmacCount(filePath)

if __name__ == "__main__":

    main()
```

It loops through a folder and count files inside all subfolders. The other file name failed_hmac.py is as follows

```
import os, sys
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from collections import Counter
import data_processed

def hmacCount(fileName):
    # Get the last failed hmac date
    fileHandle = open('file.txt',"r")
    lineList = fileHandle.readlines()
    fileHandle.close()
    lastLine = lineList[-1]
    lastDate = datetime.strptime(lastLine[:10], '%m/%d/%Y')

    with open(fileName) as f_input:

        logEntryCounts = Counter()

        #today_date = datetime.today() - timedelta(days=14)
                #print today_date
        dateRanges = [
                    ('30 Days', lastDate - timedelta(days=30)),
                    #('3 months', lastDate - timedelta(days=90)),
                    #('One year', lastDate - timedelta(days=330))
                  ]

        for line in f_input:

            #Stop Processing if there are no more lines
            if not line:

                break

            if "Following hmac" in line:

                try:
                    logDate = datetime.strptime(line[:10], '%m/%d/%Y')

                    for text, dr in dateRanges:

                        if logDate >= dr:

                            logEntryCounts[text] += 1

                except ValueError:

                    print 'This line has a problem:', logDate

    total = 0

    hmacData = float(logEntryCounts['30 Days'])

    print logEntryCounts['30 Days']

# Call The function
def main():

    filePath = 'file.txt'

    hmacCount(filePath)

if __name__ == "__main__":

    main()
```

The goal is to import **data_processed.py** into **failed_hmac.py** and use the variables **logEntryCounts** and **log_entry_counts** to perform some percentage calculations but i kept getting **logEntryCounts** **not defined error**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`data_entry_logs` is a variable inside a function in `data_processed.py`. You will have to modify your code to call the function `data_processed.dataCount()` and return the value, so that you will be able to use the variable.

In `data_processed.py`:

```
def dataCount(folderName):
    #your code
    return log_entry_counts
```

In `failed_hmac.py`:

Replace

```
hmacData = float(logEntryCounts['30 Days'])
```

with

```
hmacData = float(data_processed.dataCount(...)['30 Days'])
```

---

Another approach, which I think is the cleaner approach would be to declare both these functions in a class, as specifed in [this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10139866/calling-variable-defined-inside-one-function-from-another-function)