# Python Using variable from one function in another

Tags: python

In one function I get three pieces of information and write them to a text file.
In another function I write over one of the pieces of information (Code).

The variables `FirstName, SecondName, Code` from `function1` are not known by `function2` - how do I solve this? / Pass them from one function to another?

```
def function1():
    FirstName = input("Enter First Name")
    SecondName = input("Enter Surname")
    Code = input("Enter Code")

AllDetails = (GuestFirstName, GuestSecondName, Code)
f = open("AllDetails.txt","w") 
f.write(str(AllDetails))    
f.close()

menu()

def function2():           
    Newcode = input ("Enter if new code needed")
    if Newcode == "Y":
        Code = "****"
        AllDetails = (FirstName, SecondName, Code)
        f = open("AllDetails.txt","w") 
        f.write(str(AllDetails))
        f.close()

menu()
```

Comment: Check this out : https://stackoverflow.com/a/10139935/7977464

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about `return` the values of the function and assign them to variables like this

```
def function1():
    FirstName = input("Enter First Name")
    SecondName = input("Enter Surname")
    Code = input("Enter Code")
    return FirstName, SecondName, Code
```

Then you can assign them and use them in the rest of your code

```
FirstName, SecondName, Code = fucntion1()
```

You can even now pass those into `fucntion2()` like this

```
def function2(FirstName, SecondName, Code);
    ....
```

And then call `function2` like this

```
function2(FirstName, SecondName, Code)
```

I would suggest using generic names in your function definitions and also using snake_case over camel_case

Here is how I would revise the entire thing :

```
def get_info():
    first = input("Enter First Name")
    second = input("Enter Surname")
    user_code = input("Enter Code")
    return  first, second, user_code

def write_info(f_name, s_name, code_in):
    new_code  = input ("Enter if new code needed")
    if new_code == "Y":
        code_in = "****"
        all_details = (f_name, s_name, code_in)
        f = open("AllDetails.txt","w")
        f.write(str(all_details))
        f.close()
    else:
        pass

first_name, second_name, code = get_info()
write_info(first_name, second_name, code)

all_details = (guest_first, guest_second, code)
f = open("AllDetails.txt","w") 
f.write(str(all_details))
f.close()

menu()
```

Again not sure what the overall goal is, but this will help you with some issues that are preventing you from getting there. There is missing information here, `menu` has no definition.

Comment: I had already tried this. But when I try and return the values, the code just stops running at that point.
It does not return to the main menu (from which I get to the second function.

Comment: Yes I know and I understand, not being rude but I would step back a few steps before you get into attempting writing and working with files and really drill in how to use functions, I would recommend Python Crash Course and Automate the Boring Stuff, and of course Stack Overflow has tons of information avaiblable, best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

Variables defined inside a function are considered by python to be `Local variable`. As opposed to other programming languages, Python does not require a local variable to explicitly being declared so, but rather uses the surrounding context to determine whether a variable is global or local.

If you want to use the three variables `first_name`,`second_name`, `code` for both functions, you have two options:

**Option 1**:

Move the three variables outside of the function definition, so that they become global.

**Option 2**:

Pass the variables from one function to the other.

As far as the specific program you are writing, I would go for the first. I have edited your code accordingly, please read the comments for further indications on how to improve your writing.

```
first_name = input("Enter First Name: ") # Note the lowercase names for the 
second_name = input("Enter Surname: ")   # variables. This is not obligatory,
code = input("Enter Code: ")             # but it is good practice.

def function1():

    all_details = first_name+'_'+second_name # the + replaces the tuple,
                                   # because filename that you want to create must be
                                   # necessarily a string, not a tuple
    f = open(all_details+'.txt',"w") 
    f.write(first_name+','+second_name+','+code)    
    f.close()

# menu() # I presume menu() is the function that does something magical,
         # and either calls function1() or function2(). You don't want to call it twice probably

def function2():

    new_code_needed = input ("Enter \'Y\' if new code needed: ")
    if new_code_needed == "Y":
        code = "****"
        all_details = first_name+'_'+second_name # Same as above
        f = open(all_details+".txt","w") 
        f.write(first_name+','+second_name+','+code)
        f.close()

menu()
```