# Referencing variable from a def block in another def block

Tags: python

Basically I have this section of code that goes like so:

```
def start():

def blockA():
    y = 3
    x = 4
    print("hello")
blockA()

def blockB():
    if x !=y:
        print("not the same")
blockB()
start()
```

However, this gives me an error saying that x and y are not defined. How would I go about referencing the x and y variables in blockB?

Comment: You don't. Those are *local* variables. If you want data to be accessible outside of your function, you should *return that data from your function*

Comment: you could declare them global.  but DON'T do that.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga how would i go about returning it and then referencing it in the next block?

Comment: [Calling variable defined inside one function from another function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10139866/calling-variable-defined-inside-one-function-from-another-function)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return the variables in blockA function and call that function in your second function.

```
def blockA():
    y = 3
    x = 4
    print("hello")
    return x,y


def blockB():
    x,y=blockA()
    if x !=y:
        print("not the same")
```

This should work for you.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much!

Comment: If the answer helped you please accept the answer and upvote it. Thanks in Advance :)