# How to call one function to another in flask

Tags: python, flask

I have flask page, I need to call count and empname variable to next function

```
@app.route('/second_page',methods=['GET','POST'])
def second_page():
    empname= request.form.get('empname')
    #second_page.empname = empname
    cursor.execute("select count(*) from emp where empname = %s", (empname))
    count = cursor.fetchone() ##
    #second_page.count = cursor.fetchone()
@app.route('/third_page',methods=['GET','POST'])
def third_page():
    if request.method == 'POST':
      name = request.form.get('name')
      uniqueid = request.form.get('uniqueid')
    if(second_page.count[0] > 0): ## This count is coming from second_page function
      dirName = os.path.join('static', second_page.empname + name + uniqueid)  ## This empname is coming from second_page
      os.mkdir(dirName)
```

What i have tried declare a variable as from suggestion [Calling variable defined inside one function from another function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10139866/calling-variable-defined-inside-one-function-from-another-function)

in the second_page function i have added `second_page.count = cursor.fetchone()`, `second_page.count = cursor.fetchone()`

I got the error TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use flask session global variable. Please refer to:
https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.session