# Call a variable in one function from another function inside a class

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10139866/calling-variable-defined-inside-one-function-from-another-function/10139935#10139935) answer and trying to call a variable of one function from another function, but getting an error. Below is my test code.

```
import datetime
from datetime import timedelta
import time

class TimeTesting:
    def TimeTest1(self):
        T1 = datetime.datetime.now()
        time.sleep(5)
        print('TimeTest1 is being called')

    def TimeTest2(self):
        T2 = datetime.datetime.now()
        TimeDiff = T2 - self.T1
        print('Timetest2 has been called')
        print('Time diff is {}'.format(TimeDiff))

ob = TimeTesting()
ob.TimeTest1()
ob.TimeTest2()
```

Below is the error that I am getting -

> TimeDiff = T2 - self.T1 AttributeError: 'TimeTesting' object has no
> attribute 'T1'

Can someone point me out what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need to define T1 as an instance variable:

```
self.T1 = datetime.datetime.now()
```

As it stands, T1 is just a local variable to method `TimeTest1`, and is only in scope in that method.