# how to send value in a function inside a class to a function in another class

Tags: python, python-class

This question was assumed to be a duplicate but it is not. The suggested answer does not work. this was the suggested answer, [Calling variable defined inside one function from another function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10139866/calling-variable-defined-inside-one-function-from-another-function)

below are two classes base_step and logoclick_step.

In the function inside base_step (login), there is a variable 'z'.

Now how do I access this 'z' value inside 'admin' function of logoclick_step.

The below code returns the following error.

> a = a+z NameError: name 'z' is not defined

```
class base_step:
    a = 15 
    def login(self):
        z = 110000000
        print("completed_login")
        return z



class logoclick_step(base_step):
     
      def admin(a):
          a = a+z
          print("hello",  base_step.a)
          

      

ls = logoclick_step()
ls.login()
ls.admin()
```

Comment: This does not get the job done

Comment: The suggested answer also does not work if you are implementing the functions  in two different classes

Comment: You can define `login` as `staticmethod` as it does not use any class property inside of it and call in `admin` method to get the `z`. Or, you can define `z` as property of `base_step` class and use it in `logoclick_step` when it inherits from `base_step`

Comment: @9769953. I am unable to implement your solution

Comment: @ArtyomVancyan , I am sorry I am unable to understand what you are saying. How would I define 'z' as property?

Comment: for example `a` is a property of `base_step` class as it defined outside of methods

Comment: oh, Ok. I understand that. But I want 'z' to be defined inside the function only and then be callled. @ArtyomVancyan

Comment: Then please change definition of `admin` method to `def admin(self):` and next line `self.a = self.a + self.login()`